OpenCV pose estimation change of basis
I'm trying to change the basis from a pose obtained from a charuco pattern.
I want to change the basis from openCV to another one

My first approach was to define a transformation matrix and multiply it to the camera pose:
M_permute = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1], [1, 0, 0]])
camera_pose = M_permute @ camera_pose

But this not works as expected...
When I apply the following formula:
camera_pose  = M_permute.T @ camera_pose  @ M_permute

Everything it's ok.
Could you explain me why?

M_permute looks wrong, does not agree with the picture. you can build the matrix by considering where-to each source dimension is mapped (matrix from three column vectors).
